How to stop jconsole from attempting to use SSL?
Every time I start jconsole to check on a remote application, it attempts to use SSL -- and only failing that asks, if I'd like to try to connect insecurely. The delay -- and the extra click -- are getting on my nerves.
Is there any way to cause it to start in that insecure mode?
